# Prevent ScrollViewer from handling Tap event in a ListBox item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

Having a `ScrollViewer` as the `DataTemplate` in a `ListBox` causes `Tap event` to be handled, and therefore the `SelectedItem` value can't be changed by the user selection.

How can I override this behavior?

For example, Tapping the StackPanel in the following XAML would not trigger SelectedItem change:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TheSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding TheSelected, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"                                         >
                <StackPanel Width="100" Background="Black" Height="50" Margin="12"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I'm looking for a solution that will work on a WP8 application, and that will not change the normal scrolling behavior.

Comment: I haven't got a WP8 environment to test it, but couldn't create an event handler for the `Tap` event on the `ScrollViewer`, and mark the event as `Handled=false`?

Comment: Tried it... it seems to affect nothing.

Comment: D'oh, does the handler get called? Mighty be worth trying to chase the event path.

Comment: Yes, the handle is called. Maybe the answer is to manually fire that event on the parent when caught in the ScrollViewer_Tap handler?

Answer (score 0):

WPF ScrollViewer handles selection internally, hence Your `e.handled = false` doesn't work.

There's an easy solution though. You have to derive the `ScrollViewer` class:

```
public class CustomScrollViewer : ScrollViewer
{
    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do nothing!
           // or
       // base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e) ; e.handled = false; --to support selection //in the ScrollViewer .didn't try this one though!!
    }
}
```

Save the class in the project and use it like that:

```
...
xmlns:test="clr-namespace:WpfApplication"
...

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TheSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding TheSelected, Mode=TwoWay}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <test:CustomScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"                                         >
            <StackPanel Width="100" Background="Black" Height="50" Margin="12"/>
        </test:CustomScrollViewer>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Nice idea. However: cannot derive from sealed type 'System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer'

Comment: Jeez, that sucks. I'm using NET 3.5 and it works because ScrollViewer isn't sealed.